# Concatenate multiple result rows of one column into differents rows (horizontal)

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have the following query (SQL SERVER):

```
select id,id_nivel_estructura from estructuras_empleado where id in (1,2)
```

The result is the following:

[image]

but I want to display in columns in the following way:

```
 1 | 4 | 67 | 146 | 345 | 2158

 2 | 3 | 34 | 267 | 345 | 2152
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Its not `Group_concat` it's `Pivot`. He wants to display in different column

Comment: I'm sorry, I've vote to reopen it.

Comment: @VR46, my mistakes. I'd be very careful next time. Thanks.